# installing symfony 2, installer failed to load the https stream

Tags: php, windows, symfony, composer-php

i am having problem with installing symfony2, specifically running this command:

```
php installer  //installer is from getcomposer page
```

error is:

```
Download failed: file_get_contents (https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar): 
failed to open stream: The attempt to connect failed because the connected party 
after a time did not properly respond or established connection failed because 
connected host computer failed to respond.
```

Naturally,  i though problem is that https stream is not enabled in php, or that openssl is not loaded but that is not the problem.

Running

```
  php -r var_dump(stream_get_wrappers());
```

i checked that https wrapper is there. Also, in php.ini (correct one, the one i use for php command line use) have php_openssl loaded and also allow_url_open is On. 
I also cannot find any related error in php error log or apache error log. Any suggestion what can be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried the `curl` method?

Comment: after running curl command (curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php) nothing was reported.  I used git bash tool, even though i installed curl in windows. If i did the command directly in cmd it only stood there and it seems like it is stuck. PHP file installer send some feedback if everything was successful so i guess it still isn’t working.

Comment: Ah Windows. Can't help you there I am afraid

Comment: ok, i fixed one problem. curl worked after i specify proxy parameters.  like curl --proxy my_proxy --url composer_url but later on that script is using file_get_contents again and i am back to my original problem :)

Comment: It looks like an issue with your connection, is this from a local machine? What happens if you go to https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar ?

Comment: browser is able to load that page. I am trying to access remote file, not local one. Well, it looks like ill just download directly composer.phar and then run it locally. It seems to be that some configuration also needs to be setup so file_get_contents works behind proxy. Btw i am behind company proxy so i have limited rights in configuring network.

Comment: Ah yes, that would be the issue then. remember to put stuff like that into your original question.